# Laravel 4: Joining two tables using Eloquent for multiple database connections

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am facing a problem with joining two tables using Eloquent for multiple database connections(Example Main database,DB1 ,DB2,DB3 and so on). Let me explain in brief below:-

Suppose, I have two tables 1. Categories and 2. Products. Models for both the tables are below:-

1) Category.php

class Category extends Eloquent{

```
public $timestamps = false;

protected $table = 'categories;
protected $fillable = array('v_name','e_status');

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product,'i_category_id');
}
```

}

2) Product.php

class Product extends Eloquent{

```
public $timestamps = false;

protected $table = products;
protected $fillable = array('v_name',’i_category_id’,'e_status');

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category,'i_category_id');
}
```

}

Now, in ProductController.php

```
$objProduct = new Product; 
$objProduct->setDBConnection($objdataAuth->v_db_name);  // dynamic database connection name
$arrProductDetail = $objProduct->get()->section_activities()->get();
```

$arrProductDetail does not retrieve the information related to category(i.e of dynamic database). But, it retrieves the category of Main database(i.e in app/database.php). 
If we only take $objProduct->get() then it retrieves all the product of new database(DB1, DB2....)
But after some rnd we found that eloquent ORM uses multiple select queries rather than join.

What is our concept is we have one main database and other dynamic database created from the system. We need to connect multiple database tables for some functionality, which we cannot right now. We cannot override the Main database join with the new dynamic one.

Can we have any solution of this? Also does Laravel provide the functionality to close/destroy the previous connection and connect the new DB(Like Core PHP)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add below code in app/database.php

```
'mysql_dynamic_connection' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host',
            'database'  => 'db_name',
            'username'  => 'username',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

Now, Add below line in both model Product and Category,

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_dynamic_connection';
```

Now, set use the database connection in controller file as

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql_dynamic_connection.database', $objdataAuth->v_db_name);
```

where mysql_dynamic_connection = another database connection in app/database.php and $objdataAuth->v_db_name = Your database connection name

```
$objProduct = new Product; 
$arrProductDetail = $objProduct->where('id','=',1)->first()->categories()->get();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($arrProductDetail);
```

You will get the category array of product whose id is 1.

Thanks,
Monang Shah